# Swift type annotation for an image

Tags: ios, swift

I try to create a Swift struct with a text and an img. I know that I should use String for text, Int or Double for numbers, but what about an img? If I do not use a type annotation I have an error.

```
struct First {
    var text : String
    var image
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS you use `UIImage` in OS X `NSImage`.

Comment: I write var 'image : UIImage' and I still have an error Use or undeclared type 'UIImage'

Comment: @segon you also have to import it with `import UIKit`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import UIKit

struct TypedImage {
    var text: String
    var image: UIImage?
}
```

Alternatively, if could just store the image name and create the image on the fly.

```
import UIKit

struct TypedImage {
   var text: String
   var extension: String
   var fileName: String

   func image() -> UIImage? {
      return UIImage.(named: "\(filename).\(extension)")
   }

   // or more "Swifty": 
   var image : UIImage? {
      get { return UIImage.(named: "\(filename).\(extension)") }
   }

}
```

Comment: Why do I need ? with img and not with text?

Comment: You could just store the image name and create the image on the fly via a function.